# 403 forbitted error with python3 urllib.request

Tags: python-3.5, urlopen

I was trying to access a website and see if i can read its content using the urlopen module of urllib.import but then i see i got 403 forbidden error.

But when I try and open the link via web browser it opens. It appeared to me this is some kind of security by website to probably prevent malicious attack.

I wanted to know what are the mechanism to keep my content accessible via web browser but then prevent access via script such as which i am running ?

{code}

```
 >>> from urllib.request import urlopen
 >>> html= urlopen("http://www.english-for-students.com/A-Wise-Counting.html")
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
     response = meth(req, response)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
     return self._call_chain(*args)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
     result = func(*args)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in      http_error_default
     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
 >>>
```

{code}

Comment: I think you should change the title and the question doesn't really relate to the title.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to check the headers for a compatible browser user agent. More information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Answer (score 1):

Check the section titled "Headers" in [this link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/urllib2.html). From the page

> Some websites dislike being browsed by programs, or send different
>   versions to different browsers. By default urllib identifies
>   itself as Python-urllib/x.y (where x and y are the major and minor
>   version numbers of the Python release, e.g. Python-urllib/2.5), which
>   may confuse the site, or just plain not work. The way a browser
>   identifies itself is through the User-Agent header [3]. When you
>   create a Request object you can pass a dictionary of headers in.